# SQL Query to get the distinct dates which are at least 10 days apart

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, recursive-query

I have a table which consists of dates and names. I want to group the result by names and dates with a condition that the resultant dates selected are at least 10 days apart. (starting from first date present in the table for that name)

This is an example:

```
________________________
Names    |      Dates    
-----------------------
John     |      2-2-2000
________________________
John     |      5-2-2000
________________________
John     |      16-2-2000
________________________
John     |      17-2-2000
________________________
John     |      20-2-2000
________________________
John     |      31-2-2000
________________________
John     |      5-3-2000
________________________
John     |      14-3-2000
________________________
```

The output of the query should be the sum of count of these values  (John,2-2-2000),(John,16-2-2000),(John,31-2-2000),(John,14-3-2000) That is, 4.

How do I write a query in SQL Server for this?

Comment: You should expand your data with a few more rows so it is more representative. For example, if there were more rows for John with dates `'25-2-2000'` and `'15-3-2000'`, what would the result look like?

Comment: @GMB ,I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks. Side note: Feb 31st is not a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, because you need to keep track of the last row that was "picked" to select the next one. This means that you need to kind of iterative process, which in turns suggests a recursive query:

```
with 
    data as (
        select t.*, row_number() over(partition by names order by dates) rn
        from mytable t
    ),
    rcte as (
        select d.*, dates dates_base from data d where rn = 1
        union all
        select 
            d.*, 
            case when d.dates >= dateadd(day, 10, r.dates_base) then d.dates else r.dates_base end
        from rcte r
        inner join data d on d.rn = r.rn + 1 and d.names = r.names  
    )
select names, count(distinct dates_base) res from rcte group by names
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71713cf4db4bbf6eb203fd4597550252)**:

```
names | res
:---- | --:
John  |   4
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. The column names mentioned in the question were changes. now when I am trying to run the query I get all errors, can you please alter the query?

names = EmployeeCode
dates = DistussionDate 

and the table name is Oneoonefeedback.


Please excuse me . I am kinda new to SQL

Comment: @VishnuSayanthAV: this uses columns `dates` and `names`, as in your question. You can also refer to the demo I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  Also consistent with your desired results is that you want to count rows where the gap from the previous row is 10+ days.  For that, simply use `lag()`:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by name) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date is null or prev_date < dateadd(day, -10, date);
```

Use `select *` to get the list of records.